# EF code first unable to do commit on a non-complex null object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am currently using EF code first with SQL Server.

Here is my code:

```
public class Article
{
    public Article(string title, ValidPeriod published)
    {
        this.Title = title;
        this.Published = published;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }   
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public ValidPeriod Published { get; set; }
}

public class ValidPeriod()
{
    public DateTime From { get; set; }
    public DateTime To { get; set; }
}
```

I am able to create an instance of an Article class, but when I try to persist an Article with null ValidPeriod I am getting "Null value for non-nullable member.". How can I resolve this issue ie. how can a null class be persisted. I am not declaring ValidPeriod as complex object.

Comment: If it is not a complex object, it must have an ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to first define a primary key `Id` for `ValidPeriod` entity as the following:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Then adding an explicit nullable foreign key to `Article` entity (`int?` as nullable `int`):

```
public int? ValidPeriodId { get; set; }
```

And finally defining the relationship for `Article` entity using fluent api:

```
HasOptional(c => c.Published)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(c => c.ValidPeriodId);
```